# Animación CSS se bloquea durante ejecución de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animación

Estoy desarrollando una página de carga que se mostrará mientras el contenido de la página en sí es procesado. Es un texto simple que parpadea, mientras unos círculos de mueven de izquierda a derecha.

El problema es que durante los momentos en los que JavaScript se está procesando de forma intensiva, se bloquea la animación y se queda congelada. Un compañero me comentó que podría ser un problema al cambiar la posición y tamaño de los elementos con CSS (porque el parpadeo sí parece funcionar sin problemas).

¿Cómo puedo evitar este comportamiento? ¿Qué podría hacer para que la animación siga siendo fluida en lugar de ir a saltos?

Éste es el código con una carga forzada para que se vea el bloqueo:

```js
// código para crear bloqueo al generar alta intensidad de JS
setInterval(function() {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    let o = new Array(20000);
  }
}, 1500);
```

```css
@keyframes csLoadingBlink {
  0%, 80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes csLoadingMoveButton {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 1rem;
    width: 0rem;
    height: 0rem;
    left: 100%;
  }
}


.cs-loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.cs-brand {
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: csLoadingBlink 3s linear infinite;
}

.cs-brand span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000369;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cs-name {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.cs-name sup {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.cs-slogan {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.cs-animation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.cs-animation span,
.cs-animation::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000369;
}


.cs-animation span {
  animation: csLoadingMoveButton 3s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.cs-animation span:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.cs-animation span:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.cs-animation span:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-loading">
  <div class="cs-brand">
    <span class="cs-name">Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a</span>
    <span>Mejor Slogan del Mundo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cs-animation">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Dependiendo de lo que necesites hacer con los arrays_, podrías probar a utilizar [arrays tipados](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Vectores_tipados)
Si en tú ejemplo reemplazo `let o = new Array(20000);` con `let o = new Uint8Array(20000);`las cosas mejoran bastante. PD: no se porque en castellano los llaman vectores. En inglés siguen arrays

Comment: Los arrays son solo una demo para causar el bloqueo. No están relacionados con el código que lo causa en realidad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Cómo puedo evitar este comportamiento? ¿Qué podría hacer para que la animación siga siendo fluida en lugar de ir a saltos?

### Introducción:

Actualmente existen cuatro cosas que [el navegador puede animar a "*bajo precio*"](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/): `translate`, `scale`, `rotate` y `opacity`.

Si anima cualquier otra cosas lo más probable es que no alcance los `60fps`.

### Problema:

Como bien señalas en tu pregunta, el problema se debe a que estas cambiando la posición y tamaño de los elementos usando:

- `left` y `top` para cambiar la posición.
- `width` y `height` para cambiar el tamaño.

Como vimos anteriormente, estas reglas no están dentro de las reglas optimizadas para animaciones.

### Solución:

Para cambiar la posición podemos reemplazar `top` y `left` por [`transform: translate(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) y para cambiar el tamaño podemos reemplazar `height` y `width` por [`transform: scale(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)

Entonces:

- Para animar el cambio de posición de izquierda a derecha (`coodenada x`) podemos usar `translate(x)`.
- Para animar el cambio de tamaño proporcional podemos usar `scale(n)`.
- Para mantener centrado el elemento mientras se escala podemos usar `transform-origin: center;`

#### Ejemplo sin modificar el markup:

```js
// código para crear bloqueo al generar alta intensidad de JS
setInterval(function() {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    let o = new Array(20000);
  }
}, 1500);
```

```css
@keyframes csLoadingBlink {
  0%,
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes csLoadingMoveButton {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(.5) translate(42rem);
  }
}

.cs-loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.cs-brand {
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: csLoadingBlink 3s linear infinite;
}

.cs-brand span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000369;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cs-name {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.cs-name sup {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.cs-slogan {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.cs-animation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.cs-animation span,
.cs-animation::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000369;
}

.cs-animation span {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: csLoadingMoveButton 3s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.cs-animation span:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.cs-animation span:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.cs-animation span:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-loading">
  <div class="cs-brand">
    <span class="cs-name">Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a</span>
    <span>Mejor Slogan del Mundo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cs-animation">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Ejemplo 2 modificando el markup:

```js
// código para crear bloqueo al generar alta intensidad de JS
setInterval(function() {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    let o = new Array(20000);
  }
}, 1500);
```

```css
@keyframes csLoadingBlink {
  0%,
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.cs-loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.cs-brand {
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: csLoadingBlink 3s linear infinite;
}

.cs-brand span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000369;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cs-name {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.cs-name sup {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.cs-slogan {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.cs-animation {
  height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

@keyframes csLoadingMoveButton {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(22rem);
  }
}

.cs-animation div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  animation: csLoadingMoveButton 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes csLoadingScaleButton {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(.1);
  }
}

.cs-animation span,
.cs-animation::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000369;
}

.cs-animation span {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: csLoadingScaleButton 3s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.cs-animation div:nth-of-type(1),
.cs-animation div:nth-of-type(1) span {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.cs-animation div:nth-of-type(2),
.cs-animation div:nth-of-type(2) span {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.cs-animation div:nth-of-type(3),
.cs-animation div:nth-of-type(3) span {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-loading">
  <div class="cs-brand">
    <span class="cs-name">Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a</span>
    <span>Mejor Slogan del Mundo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cs-animation">
    <div><span></span></div>
    <div><span></span></div>
    <div><span></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Usando un worker pareciera que no se traba

( ejemplo inline tomado de https://stackoverflow.com/a/6454685/1423096 )

el `if ( 5 > Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) ) {` es para que el console.log no afecte el render.

```js
// código para crear bloqueo al generar alta intensidad de JS
/*
setInterval(function() {
  for (let j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    let o = new Array(20000);
  }
}, 1500);
//*/

var blob = new Blob([document.querySelector('#worker1').textContent], {
  type: "text/javascript"
})

// Note: window.webkitURL.createObjectURL() in Chrome 10+.
var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log("Received: " + e.data);
}
worker.postMessage("hello"); // Start the worker.
```

```css
@keyframes csLoadingBlink {
  0%,
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes csLoadingMoveButton {
  0% {
    top: 0;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    top: 1rem;
    width: 0rem;
    height: 0rem;
    left: 100%;
  }
}

.cs-loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.cs-brand {
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: csLoadingBlink 3s linear infinite;
}

.cs-brand span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000369;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cs-name {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.cs-name sup {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

.cs-slogan {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.cs-animation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.cs-animation span,
.cs-animation::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000369;
}

.cs-animation span {
  animation: csLoadingMoveButton 3s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}

.cs-animation span:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.cs-animation span:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.cs-animation span:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="cs-loading">
  <div class="cs-brand">
    <span class="cs-name">Compa&ntilde;&iacute;a</span>
    <span>Mejor Slogan del Mundo</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cs-animation">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<script id="worker1" type="javascript/worker">
  self.onmessage = function(e) {
    self.postMessage('msg from worker');
  };
  setInterval(
    function() {
      if ( 5 > Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) ) {
        self.postMessage('setinterval still alive');
      }
      for (let j = 0; j <
        10000; j++) {
        let o = new Array(20000);
      }
    }, 1500);
</script>
```

Comment: He añadido un `console.log(1)` dentro de la función del `setInterval`, pero no se escribe nada por la consola. Parecería que el código que fuerza el bloqueo no está corriendo. ¿Seguro que se está ejecutando ese código correctamente?

Comment: dentro del worker hay que usar el `self.postMessage` que el main thread recibe con `onmessage`  y hace `console.log`

Comment: Ok, ahora entiendo esa parte mejor (mira que habías puesto un comentario sobre eso en la respuesta). Tengo que ver cómo funcionaría esto, porque yo no tengo control sobre el JS que genera el problema, aunque puedo añadir más HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: humm si está complicado si no se puede workerizar el proceso, yo probé con svg y el mismo problema, ahora pruebo con un mp4 a ver si el render se delega a la tarjeta de video

Comment: Este es un problema real que tuvimos la semana pasada. Al final optamos por no complicarnos y usar un GIF animado (después de comprobar que los SVG también se congelaban pero los GIF no).

Comment: sep, es un tema de quién se hace cargo del render para separar los hilos de ejecución, gif me parecia medio retro para probar pero si vale vale =P

Comment: Los web workers suenan como una buena idea y están soportados en IE11... quizás puedo convencer que prueben a usar uno con el script problemático y usar animaciones con CSS/SVG.

Comment: eps dependiendo del uso de procesador del lado del cliente ( si no es posible entregar los datos ya cocinados por el servidor ) lo que mejor funciona para evitar estas situaciones es workers o volver a las bases ( c/c++) y usar webassembly